# Scala Dependent type does not compile

Tags: scala, dependent-type, path-dependent-type

This code *should* compile in Scala:

```
trait Pipe {
  type Input
  type Output
  def apply(input: Input): Output
}

object Pipe {
  trait Start extends Pipe {
    override type Input = Seq[String]
  }

  abstract class Connect(val prev: Pipe) extends Pipe {
    override type Input = prev.Output
  }
}

object Pipe1 extends Pipe.Start {
  override type Output = Int
  override def apply(input: Input): Output = 
   input.length
}

object Pipe2 extends Pipe.Connect(prev = Pipe1) {
  override type Output = Boolean
  override def apply(input: Input): Output = 
   input%2 == 0
}
```

`Pipe1` compiles fine but `Pipe2` fails to compile with:

```
value % is not a member of Pipe2.this.Input
     input%2 == 0
          ^
```

I know I can solve this with generics instead of dependent types but this should work as `Pipe2.Input` should typecheck to be `Int` from `Pipe1.Output`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `prev = Pipe` thing in the invocation of the constructor is not a proper path, the compiler cannot tie any type information to that, so you end up with a rather useless `prev.Output =:= Input` for some indeterminate `prev: Pipe` which has been set to *something* in the constructor.

With a minimal change, it works as expected:

```
trait Pipe {
  type Input
  type Output
  def apply(input: Input): Output
}

object Pipe {
  trait Start extends Pipe {
    override type Input = Seq[String]
  }

  abstract class Connect extends Pipe {
    val prev: Pipe
    override type Input = prev.Output
  }

}

object Pipe1 extends Pipe.Start {
  override type Output = Int
  override def apply(input: Input): Output = 
    input.length
}

object Pipe2 extends Pipe.Connect {
  val prev = Pipe1
  override type Output = Boolean
  override def apply(input: Input): Output = input % 2 == 0
}
```

That's why it's called *path* dependent (not *member* dependent, not *value* dependent etc.).

Comment: This works... but shouldn't the compiler know? The argument to `Connect` cannot be just "some Pipe` but a particular Pipe with a particular output type?

Comment: @pathikrit The compiler sees it this way: 1) There is a member variable `prev: Pipe`. 2) There is a type definition `type Input = prev.Output`. 3) There is a constructor that sets `prev` to some `Pipe`. That's it. The constructor could do anything. It could ignore the argument, and set the `prev` to some other `Pipe` randomly. It could hash the argument, and feed the hash into a neural network that confabulates another `Pipe` instance. There is nothing that connects the argument list of the constructor to the member variable. They just share the name `prev`, nothing more.

Comment: Whether the type system of language X should do the step Y towards some more sophisticated variant Z of a fully dependent type theory - I don't know, I'd prefer to refrain from statements like "designers of language X should implement Y", because such statements tend to be much easier to make than to do the actual implementation. Is it imaginable that there is a more sophisticated type system out there that would notice this? Yes, it's imaginable. Should the Scala-people try to implement that? I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

@Andrey-Tyukin's answer works above. I also found this work around:

```
trait Pipe {
  type Input
  type Output
  def apply(input: Input): Output
}

object Pipe {
  trait Start extends Pipe {
    override type Input = Seq[String]
  }

  abstract class Connect[O](val prev: Pipe.Emitting[O]) extends Pipe {
    override type Input = O
  }

  type Emitting[O] = Pipe {type Output = O}
}

object Pipe1 extends Pipe.Start {
  override type Output = Int
  override def apply(input: Input): Output = 
   input.length
}

object Pipe2 extends Pipe.Connect(prev = Pipe1) {
  override type Output = Boolean
  override def apply(input: Input): Output = 
   input%2 == 0
}
```

Comment: This `O`-type is no longer dependent on any paths: you're using a variant of `Aux`-pattern to move the type member `Output` into a generic type, and then you use the generic type to set `Input` to it. I think it would be worth a try to get rid of the `type Input` and `type Output` members, and just expose the input/output type as generic types. If a type is relevant to a single component, make it into type member; If it's an "interface description" for connecting multiple components, make it into a generic that is easily accessible from outside.